# How to inject inline HTML tags into the "Title" field

Tags: templates, html

**I'm in need of a solution to have this output:**

```
<h1>My Title <sup>&reg;</sup></h1>
```

**And in my template I have this:**

```
<h1>{title}</h1>
```

I was thinking that I could search for all `&regs;` within an `h1` then wrap it with the `&reg;` with the `<sup>` tag using jQuery.

Maybe i'm looking for something to not strip HTML from the title tag? Does anyone have any other solutions?

Comment: Did you ever settle on a solution, Dan?

Answer (score 4):

The [Low Replace](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-replace) plugin is ideal for this.

If your title field contains `My Title &reg;` then in your template you can do...

```
{exp:low_replace find="&reg;" replace="<sup>&reg;</sup>"}{title}{/exp:low_replace}
```

...which will output `My Title <sup>&reg;</sup>` as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am misunderstanding something, you should be able to easily do it like so

```
<h1>{title} <sup>&reg;</sup></h1>
```

Or, if you want to keep your HTML clean, use the :after pseudo-class in your CSS?

Comment: Well, <sup>&reg;</sup> needs to be output from {title}. So the <sup> tags needs to be added from within the title field.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like EE has replaced the character entity with the actual character by the time it outputs the `{title}`. So you'd have to search for the character rather than the entity.

The jQuery to do what you want would be:

```
var title = $('h1');
title.html(title.text().split('®').join('<sup>®</sup>'));
```

That would find all instances of the ® character in your h1 and wrap them in `sup` tags.

If you didn't want to use Javascript you could do it with PHP and a plugin. Let me know if you'd like to go down that route.